# Not getting textbox values in wordpress template using js

Tags: jquery

this is my html tag .Here when i get this text box value via jquery it is not getting it only shows undefined. I am using this in wordpress theme

```
<input type="text" id"txtName" value="p">
```

Comment: please ask with code in detail.

Comment: Please provide complete details with code so that we can help out

Comment: i am trying to add some details to database.Here I am using a wordpress theme which contains a textbox.I need to alert the value of text box while loading.But it only shows undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#textboxid').val();
//or 
    jQuery('.textbox').val();
});
```